# My CV says I'm a developer. How do I apply for other kinds of roles?

Tags: career-development, career-switch

Predominantly my professional experience says I'm a developer- I have strong skills across the board with the web and open source development. However, I also have some other skills such as writing and business development and have experience to back it up. However, most of the attention from recruiters are for getting me in a dev role. How, do I reply for different kinds of jobs?

Comment: You can simply let recruiters know when they approach you with dev job offers, what other roles you would be more interested in. And, as Justin noted, back it up with a suitable CV of course.

Comment: There is no rule that states you have one CV for life. You should tailor it for each job.

Comment: I think he's pointing out that it "says" he's a developer in as much as his last 10 years of experience are in development roles

Answer (score 4):

Generally, if you're looking for different types of positions, you'll want to have multiple resumes/ CVs each of which are tailored to demonstrate your suitability for one type of role.  Your programming CV would emphasize your development experience in each of your jobs.  Your writing CV would emphasize the writing you've done in each position.  The business development CV would emphasize the business development tasks you performed.  Obviously, each CV would be talking about the same positions, and each would probably mention the other skills, but the focus of your description should be on how the role prepared you for that particular field.

Comment: How does this apply to electronic resumes, like on LinkedIn, Stack Overflow Careers, etc.? Although I'm happy in my current job and my CVs reflect that I'm not actively looking for a new position, I do get contact from recruiters about development positions. I do development now, but I also do more than a good portion of process improvement (CMMI, Lean, AS9100/9115, DO-178 software processes) and project management (schedules, budgets, project execution). This is what my elective courses education focused on and what about 25-30% of my job is now, but recruiters only focus on the dev aspects.

Comment: Instead of waiting for the recruiters to approach you you should approach a recruiting agency and tell them everything you just told us.  I'm not sure where you live but most big cities have agencies who will gladly work with you on finding the job you want, including how to write and where to put your resume.